# Strange Hover Bug

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a responsive Modal Box with Images.

```
Code:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YCcNY/34/

In it, when you hover the images become bigger.
Sometimes, when hovering over the last pic in the 1st row, the format breaks.
If it doesn't for you resize the window.

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: Works great now ! Thank you very much everybody !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Zoltan's answer is very good. You could also consider using CSS transforms for the scaling. The images will be slightly blurry, but the upside is that transforms doesn't affect the actual size of the image, just the way it is rendered.

```
li:hover img {
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

Comment: Oh.. so easy ! That I didn't think on scale ! Thanks a lot ! I will select this one over Zoltan's answer because it also works with the responsive modal. A small tip: To keep it from becoming blurry, I will just start out the image with 0.9 and on hover scale it 1.0 ;)

Answer (score 2):

That's the normal behavior for floated elements with no height. To fix it give a fixed height to your `li` items - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/YCcNY/38/)

```
.PhotoContent li {
    width: 20%; 
    height: 100px; /* THIS */
    float: left;
    font-weight: 200;
    clear:none;
    color: rgb(150,150,150);
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: 0px solid green;
}
```

Comment: I can't set the height to a set value as the modal needs to be responsive and the li relative to the pic, Resize the window in width and it breaks. But thx anyways. I would give you a upvote but don't have enough rep.